# Accessing a class instance in a library from two separate scripts in a project

Tags: python, import, scoping

I searched all over and could not come up with a reasonable search query to produce helpful results. I'll try to explain this with a simple example (that is tested).

Suppose I have some small custom Python library that contains just the following private class and public instance of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class _MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "Default"

my_instance = _MyClass()
```

Now, I also have two other python files ('file_a' and 'file_b') that will end up importing this instance from my library as seen below.

The full code in 'file_a':

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from my_lib import my_instance

my_instance.val = "File A was here!"
import file_b
file_b.check_val()
```

The full code in 'file_b':

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from my_lib import my_instance

def check_val():
    print "From 'file_b', my_instance.val is: {}".format(my_instance.val)
```

The resulting output, if I only execute 'file_a' within a directory that also contains 'file_b' and 'my_lib', is this:

```
From 'file_b', my_instance.val is: File A was here!
```

Can someone explain to me how 'file_b' is able to access the same exact instance as 'file_a' in my example? Does this have to do with how the value being set in 'file_a' is global?

*By the way, I do know I can just make 'MyClass' public again and instantiate it whenever a unique instance is needed in either 'file_a' or 'file_b', but the main reason I am posting this question is to wrap my head around this specific concept.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to understand here:

### 1. Module caching

Python caches module imports to improve performance, this happens even when you do `from foo import bar`. The module object gets stored in `sys.modules`.

Hence, in your case both `file_a` and `file_b` are accessing same module object `my_lib` and same instance `my_instance`.

### 2. References

In Python variable assignment is basically adding a new reference to the same object, this is true for imports as well.

```
from my_lib import my_instance
```

is basically

```
import my_lib
my_instance = my_lib.my_instance
del my_lib
```

Now as we modify this instance in `file_a`, we have basically modified the instance in `my_lib`, and `file_b` will also see this change.

---

You can modify `file_a` and `file_b` to verify this.

`file_a`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from my_lib import my_instance

my_instance.val = "File A was here!"

print "Inside file_a"
import sys
print id(sys.modules['my_lib']), sys.modules['my_lib'].my_instance, my_instance

import file_b
file_b.check_val()
```

`file_b`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from my_lib import my_instance

print "Inside file_b"
import sys
print id(sys.modules['my_lib']), sys.modules['my_lib'].my_instance, my_instance


def check_val():
    print "From 'file_b', my_instance.val is: {}".format(my_instance.val)
```

**Output(check the object IDs):**

```
>>> %run file_a.py

Inside file_a
4396461816 <my_lib._MyClass object at 0x106158ad0> <my_lib._MyClass object at 0x106158ad0>
Inside file_b
4396461816 <my_lib._MyClass object at 0x106158ad0> <my_lib._MyClass object at 0x106158ad0>
From 'file_b', my_instance.val is: File A was here!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `import my_lib` in each file and then `print(id(my_lib))`, you'll see that the only a single module object is created.

Reading [The `import` system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) from the python docs may help you understand what's going on here. Of particular relevance is the section on [The module cache](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache). In part:

> The first place checked during `import` search is `sys.modules`. This
>   mapping serves as a cache of all modules that have been previously
>   imported, including the intermediate paths. So if `foo.bar.baz` was
>   previously imported, `sys.modules` will contain entries for `foo`,
>   `foo.bar`, and `foo.bar.baz`. Each key will have as its value the
>   corresponding module object.
>
> During import, the module name is looked up in `sys.modules` and if
>   present, the associated value is the module satisfying the import, and
>   the process completes.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot more sense. I was not aware of how python caches modules per project. I'll definitely do some reading on the import system, then. Thanks!